# How to create an in-app purchase bundle in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, xcode10

I'm trying to create my first in app purchase bundle, following [this tutorial](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_8_In-App_Purchases).

At one point it instructs me to "Using a Finder window, locate the content files that are to be hosted on the App Store and drag and drop them onto the content folder in the Xcode project navigator panel".

I'm not sure what the "content folder" is.

The tutorial has previously mentioned the content folder in the context "The folder must also contain a sub-folder named Contents in which resides the content files associated with the in-app purchase." Am I supposed to create that folder myself?

[image: XCode10 In-App Purchase: project structure]
Mt project seems to have a "Products" folder. Does this replace the mentioned "Contents" folder?

Things I've looked at to find the answer:

- [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201810/ios-how-to-upload-apple-hosted-content-to-in-app-purchase-in-itunesconnect) that tangentially addresses the question
- [This page](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev285fb60ce) on Apple's own documentation, which links to
- [This other page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) of Apple's own docs, which still don't seem to address creating the content bundle either

If anyone has a reliable resource (ideally Apple's own documentation) that tells developers how to do this, that'd be 110% wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a fair bit it looks like the answer is that it just doesn't matter. You can have any content you like in any format as a sibling to the `.plist` in my example, and uploading it to Apple's servers seems to work.

I can only conclude that the tutorial was just kidding about the 'contents' folder.